# date object not as expected using setDate

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

```
var start_date = new Date(ss.getSheetByName('3D Tracker').getRange('I119').getValue());
```

Using debugging tool start date evaluates to `Wed Oct 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)` I would like to create a new variable which is start plus 10 days.

```
var start = start_date;
var end = new Date(start.setDate(start.getDate() + 10));
```

Output of the Logger is:

```
start: Sat Oct 11 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)
end: Sat Oct 11 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```

I expected start to remain `Wed Oct 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400` and end to be `Sat Oct 11 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)`. Somehow my script is adding 10 days to start as well as end, whereas I only nat to add 10 days to end.

Am I missing something? Environment is Google Apps Script which is Javascript based.

Comment: You are calling setDate() on start, which will modify start date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`setDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) modifies the `Date` object it's called on first, before returning the value that was calculated. So, you're moving `start` up 10 days before creating `end` from that updated timestamp.

If you want to use `setDate()` without changing `start` specifically, you'll want to create the `new Date()` from it first.

```
var start = new Date(ss.getSheetByName('3D Tracker').getRange('I119').getValue());

var end = new Date(start.getValue()); // initially match `start`
end.setDate(end.getDate() + 10);      // change to 10 days later
```

---

For a one-liner, you can also calculate the new timestamp, with `10 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000` equaling the number of milliseconds in 10 days:

```
var end = new Date(start.getValue() + 10 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```